# Looking for an R function that will allow me to summarize data in a df based on matching values in 5 columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset that contains game log data from NBA games. Each row has data about a single play, which includes 10 columns showing who from each team was playing at the time. These columns are labeled A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 and H1, H2, H3, H4, H5.

Using R, I want to summarize various columns based on matching groups of players in the A1, A2... H1, H2... columns. The issue is, the players aren't grouped in the same order in every row. In the following example I need to summarize rows 1 and 3 because the both contain players 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, just not in the same order:

```
Row | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | pts 
----|----|----|----|----|----|-----
1   | p1 | p2 | p3 | p4 | p5 | 2   < row 1 equals row 3
----|----|----|----|----|----|----- 
2   | p2 | p7 | p3 | p4 | p5 | 3 
----|----|----|----|----|----|----- 
3   | p5 | p2 | p3 | p4 | p1 | 1   < row 3 equals row 1
----|----|----|----|----|----|----- 
4   | p6 | p2 | p9 | p4 | p5 | 3
```

Ideally, I would like a function that can summarize these groups straight away, but am thinking maybe I need a function that can sort each row horizontally first. Then I could create a value that concatenates the 5 columns and use that to summarize the data (that is how I do it in Excel).

I am new to R, so I'm just looking for the most efficient approach.

Comment: FYI: it really helps if the data is in a more-easily "consumed" format. Examples include: (1) build the data programmatically, e.g., with `data.frame`, not always aesthetically "awesome"; (2) same as you have but without the pipes and dashes, ala the "text" portion of my answer; (3) combination: programmatically with `read.table` or similar, using a visually easy format; or (4) output from `dput(x)` or `dput(head(x))` if large. The 3rd is good for small datasets like this. If your data has embedded spaces then it likely won't work, so either replace the spaces or choose the 4th option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a column of the fields, sorted. For example:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
Row  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  pts 
1    p1  p2  p3  p4  p5  2
2    p2  p7  p3  p4  p5  3 
3    p5  p2  p3  p4  p1  1
4    p6  p2  p9  p4  p5  3')

dat$sorted <- apply(subset(dat, select=A1:A5), 1, function(v) paste(sort(v), collapse = ","))
dat
#   Row A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 pts         sorted
# 1   1 p1 p2 p3 p4 p5   2 p1,p2,p3,p4,p5
# 2   2 p2 p7 p3 p4 p5   3 p2,p3,p4,p5,p7
# 3   3 p5 p2 p3 p4 p1   1 p1,p2,p3,p4,p5
# 4   4 p6 p2 p9 p4 p5   3 p2,p4,p5,p6,p9
```

Quick explanation:

- `subset(dat, select=...)` is a cheap way of gathering a range of named columns; could easily have done `dat[2:6]` instead;
- `apply(x, 1, FUN)` applies the function `FUN` to each row (`1`) of the the data `x`; change 1 to 2 and it'll apply on each column; the `FUN` is called in this case 4 times, once for each row, with a vector of values;
- `sort(v)` ensures that the players' IDs (or names?) are always in a predictable order;
- `paste(..., collapse=",")` takes all of the strings and compacts them into a single string, with the `,` between each of them.

So the new `sorted` column is perhaps the clearest way to ensure different rows have exactly the same players, regardless of position in the columns. It is not intended to be "beautiful", just useful. If you have a similar reporting field that you generate that is better-looking and equally a predictable order (who knows?), then it could work too.

Now you can group on this, something like:

```
dat$groupavg <- ave(dat$pts, dat$sorted, FUN=mean)
dat$groupsum <- ave(dat$pts, dat$sorted, FUN=sum)
dat
#   Row A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 pts         sorted groupavg groupsum
# 1   1 p1 p2 p3 p4 p5   2 p1,p2,p3,p4,p5      1.5        3
# 2   2 p2 p7 p3 p4 p5   3 p2,p3,p4,p5,p7      3.0        3
# 3   3 p5 p2 p3 p4 p1   1 p1,p2,p3,p4,p5      1.5        3
# 4   4 p6 p2 p9 p4 p5   3 p2,p4,p5,p6,p9      3.0        3
```